# Is there a way to hide/disable standard Salesforce button clicked

Tags: leads, standard-objects, lead-conversion, convert

Is there a way to stop standard Salesforce button being clicked? in the Lead page I have a standard button called "Convert" I want the user to stop clicking until the Lead is in certain stage, I'm thinking either we can Disabled or Hide or when the user clicked on the button some sort of message saying the **"you cannot clicked until the stage has changed to whatever"**

I have searched online and did not find anything close to what I'm trying to achieve finally thought to post here.

Answer (score 5):

**To hide the button**

This can be done with record types and page layouts

Create two record types -

- one for Leads with stages up to but not including the stage that allows conversion
- one for Leads in stages that allow conversion

Create two page layouts (use page layout assignment)

- one for the first record type,. Remove the Convert button on the page layout
- one for the second record type. Leave the Convert button on the page layout

Use Workflow or Process Builder to assign the record type based on Lead 'stage' (presumably, `Lead.Status`

**To leave the button but display an error message after the Conversion page is committed by user**

```
Validation Rule ISPICKVAL(Status,'foo') && IsConverted
```

**To advise user that Convert is not avail until status is xx**

Use 'soft alerts' - an IMAGE formula that appears at the top of the page layout with some colored flag (yellow). See [this blog post for an idea](http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/03/19/soft-alerts/)

Comment: this looks little involved is that the only option avail?

Comment: @NickKahn - some other ideas

Comment: i have created validation rule which states that `AND(ISPICKVAL(Status,'Approved Lead')) && IsConverted` and i have defined the error message but when i clicked on the convert button and my status was not `approved` and i did not get any error message, not sure if i'm following your post.

Comment: @NickKahn you want the VR to return true if the status is one you can't convert to a lead.  Plus, the VR won't resolve to true until the user fills out the confirm lead form and clicks OK

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple UI issues and you'd like to solve this issue declaratively the you should look at Skuid, this is exactly what it's designed to do. Skuid is a UX platform completely running in Salesforce.  You can see more and download a trail via the app exchange.

Comment: I take it you work for the company that develops this product?